# linux server won't display .HTML files

Tags: linux, .htaccess, webserver

Suddenly .HTML files will not load on my Linux web server (they were up to a few days ago). I get the error:

> This page isn’t working domain.com is currently unable to handle this
>   request. 
>   HTTP ERROR 500

.PHP and .HTM (without ending "L") will load.

.htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule     ^$     index.php?_path=index.html&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
RewriteRule     ^index.php$
index.php?_path=index.html&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
RewriteRule     ^index.html$
index.php?_path=index.html&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
RewriteRule     ^contact.html$
contact.php?_path=contact.html&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.html)$
page.php?_path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}      [L]
```

I don't see anything crazy in there.

Where can I look to figure out what is happening?

Comment: Is `.htaccess` the only thing that has changed on your server since `.html` was working? Error 500 is a generic, internal error, so it could be a lot of things.

Comment: is that n apache server? look at /var/log/http/error_log or similar.